# Experiments on time spent by the visual cortex

Tags: experiments, computer-vision

I'm working on a object detection problem, using convolutional neural networks which have a lot in common with how the human visual cortex works. I've previously seen remarks on tasks in computer vision like "if a human can do it in x milliseconds, it can easily be solved by a computer".

I was thinking of setting up an experiment where I flash an image for a set amount of time and the subject records whether (s)he detected the object or not. I would then have multiple subjects, a large set of images, and a varying flash length. Thus I could kind of quantify how hard my computer vision task is.

My question is whether you know of any research, papers, books or other resources on this subject? Any resources specifically linked to neural networks and deep learning would be especially helpful.